# execute cron with shell using cake php

Tags: cakephp

currently I am using command to execute cron is

cd appfolder.
../cake/console/cake cronname

it is working on local linux server
but,

(1)
/home/chpltv/public_html/cron/cron/cake/console/cake -app "/home/chpltv/public_html/cron/cron/app" news_import_basic >> /home/chpltv/public_html/cron/a.txt

(2) sh ../home/chpltv/boxyourtvtrial.com/cake/console/cake.php -app "/home/chpltv/boxyourtvtrial.com/public_html/cron/cron/app/" news_import_basic >> /home/chpltv/public_html/cron/a.txt

it is not working.

I dont know wht is issue......

Please Help me

please tell me command to run cron in cake php

Answer (score 2):

A shell is run from the app/vendors/shells directory within the application you have created. When you create the shell, if must also follow the same class structure as the other class based code in cake:

```
class ThisNewNameShell extends Shell {
 // functions here
}
```

Then this shell is called run with the following command:

```
/path/to/cake/console/cake {name_of_shell} {name_of_function} {args} -app /path/to/app
```

If you still are not getting the desired results, turn on debugging and run the shell manually to see the output and fix any issues. Once they are resolved, you will have a working cron.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Without any error messages, it's hard to diagnose a problem.

Check your email or cron logs (possibly /var/log/cron) for error messages, they may help.

Check the permissions on your files to ensure the cron user can run the cake console etc.

Assuming you have php cli working fine (should be ok if you can run it manually on the same server), is it in the path when the cron executes?

Consider appending 2>/tmp/news_import_basic.err to the cron commands to capture any error messages to a log file.